# Greeter Font and Session Chooser

Tags: release-juno, settings, display, greeter, themes

On Juno is there a way to change the Pantheon-greeter font? I tried various things in /etc/lightdm/* and /usr/share/lightdm/* but nothing seemed to affect the font. gsettings didn't find anything relevant either. Hard coded?

Raleway is a great font; just want to mix it up a bit for some of the lab systems so I know what is what at a glance regardless of what the KVM is set to.

Also, how would I go about completely removing the session chooser from the greeter screen? I don't want these boxes ever going into anything other than Pantheon.

I suppose I could add a custom lightdm theme but want to avoid that if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: What is update? Have you able to change it? What guide did you follow to edit the lightdm?

Comment: Gave up. Migrated hosts to a different OS.